# Linked Measure Groups and Local Dimensions

Tags: sql, ssas, data-warehouse

Mulling over something I've been reading up on.

According to [Chris Webb](http://www.packtpub.com/article/measures-and-measure-groups-microsoft-analysis-services-part2),

> A linked measure group can only be
>   used with dimensions from the same
>   database as the source measure group.

So I took this to mean as long as two cubes share a database, a linked measure group can be used with a dimension.  So I created a new cube and added a local measure group, a local dimension and a linked measure group. However, I can't create a relationship between the linked measure group and the local dimension even though they are within the same database. I get the message below:

> Regular relationships in the current
>   database between non-linked (local)
>   dimensions and linked measure groups
>   cannot be edited.  These relationship
>   can only be created through the
>   wizard.  This dialog can be used to
>   delete these relationships.

I see that I can go to the original cube and add the dimension there, but does the message below mean I have an alternative?

I just know it's going to be something simple and trivial! Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to do what I think you're doing then add the other cube first (the one you tried to link to the original) and then go to the linked dimensions tab and do the linking and it should work. 
Be sure to check your aggregation after you do the linking because often-times that can get goofy if your two cubes use that dimension in different ways even though they are essentially both accessing the same dimension.